# bubble sort. C++

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

What is wrong with my bubble sort code and how do I get it to write out after sorting (before the Linesearch).

I've used code based on the only example I could find in the book.  Searched around the net for some guide on how to sort an array list by age but I could not find one (at least, not one that wasn't too advanced for me). So I'm back with another piece of code that probably will make your eyes bleed ^^ Sorry.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class person
{
public:
string name;
int age;

void SetInfo(const string _name, int _age)
{
    name = _name;
    age = _age;
}
int getAge(){ return age; }
};

int Linearsearch(person* personarray, int key)
{
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (personarray[i].age == key)
        return i;
}
return -1;
}

void bubblesort(person mylist[], int n)
{
for (int i = 1; i<n; i++)
{

    for (int j = 0; j<n - 1; j++)
    {
        if (mylist[j].getAge() > mylist[j + 1].getAge())
        {
            person temp;
            temp = mylist[j];
            mylist[j] = mylist[j + 1];
            mylist[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
}

int main()//start of program
{
person mylist[4];//List of people
mylist[0].SetInfo("Calle", 22);
mylist[1].SetInfo("Björn", 20);
mylist[2].SetInfo("Larry", 60);
mylist[3].SetInfo("Lena", 54);

//calling bubblesort()
bubblesort(mylist, 4);


int index = Linearsearch(mylist, 20);

if (index == -1)
    cout << "person not found!";
else
    cout << "the person you searched for " << mylist[index].name;

cin.get();
return 0;
system("pause");
}
```

I've commented the errors I get from the code I have with //.

First of all, I do not even know it the bubble sort code I have here will target the age and sort it like I would like it to.

I've tried the rest of the code without the bubble sort code and it actually works just fine (:D).
Any and all help with the bubble sort code or how to get it to show after sorting would be nice.
Please vote down my question or tell me how I could reform it to make it less annoying instead of just complaining.  And feel free to help me edit anything in my question (if you can).

Comment: The compiler has told you what the main problem is - you need to pass the array and list size in as arguments/paramters to bublesort, else it cannot operate on them because they are declared as locals in main() or not at all:(

Comment: So "n" needs to be 4 in this case? :( I'm swedish so the English makes  it hard to understand at times >< If I got this right I could rename n to max and set max to 4?  To make it more clear to me

Comment: First of all - why are you using variables, which are not declared anywhere? (like `n` in bubblesort or `list` in main)? Try reading a little about C++ (the best would be the most basic tutorial).

Comment: About printing list - why are you calling `list.display()`. Is display a function connected to any class? No. So just call it (but pass it your array, because it does not know what mylist is, it's out of scope).

Comment: I'v removed that since I last edited the code. It was a stupid try to print out the sorted list before the linesearch :P Still haven't figured out how to get the list printed before Linesearch :c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you have declared `mylist` in main function and trying to access it in `bubblesort` function which is not a part of person class. Other thing is that you cannot compare two object as you are doing to sort the list. You can sort mylist object list on the basis of age member variable. Add `getAge()` method in person class.

```
class person
{
    public:
        string name;
        int age; 

    void SetInfo(const string _name, int _age)
    {
        name = _name;
        age = _age;
    }
    int getAge(){return age;}
};

   void bubblesort(person mylist[],int n)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i<n; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j<n - 1; j++) //n is "undefined" should n be the number of objects in the list maybe?
            {
                if (mylist[j].getAge() > mylist[j + 1].getAge()) //the first mylist is "undefined".
                {
                    person temp;
                    temp = mylist[j];
                    mylist[j] = mylist[j + 1];
                    mylist[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
int main()//start of program
{
    person mylist[4];//List of people
    mylist[0].SetInfo("Calle", 22);
    mylist[1].SetInfo("Björn", 20);
    mylist[2].SetInfo("Larry", 60);
    mylist[3].SetInfo("Lena", 54);

    //calling bubblesort()
    bubblesort(mylist,4);

    //list.display(); //list is undefined.

    int index = Linesearch(mylist, 20);

    if (index == -1)
        cout << "person not found!";
    else
        cout << "the person you searched for " << mylist[index].name;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
    system("pause");
}
```

I think this should work. phewww...

Comment: Thanks mate! So I should add a getage() after the string name and int age in the person class? what exactly will that do and how do I make that method?

Comment: YES! gives no errors, now I just need to make something that shows the sorted list before linesearch :D Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: Why are you trying to use variables names you didn't declare anywhere? (like list)

Comment: Oh, yeah. Sorry, forgot mate! Thanks a lot for the help! going through the code to understand everything :P the setinfo? tried a lot of code first and it just ended up staying, and now everything works ^^

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
for (int j = 0; j<n - 1; j++)
```

to

```
for (int j = 0; j<i - 1; j++)
```

in your bubblesort function

Answer (score 1):

i just took a quick look but i don't think you declared n before you used it in bubble sort. 
also, i don't think that what you do there is bubble sort. try this:

```
void bubblesort()
{
    int k=1;
    while (k==1)
        {
            k=0;
            for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
            {
                if (mylist[i]>=mylist[i-1])
                {
                    temp=mylist[i];
                    mylist[i]=mylist[i-1];
                    mylist[i-1]=temp;
                    k=1;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

modify it for your example and i'm sure it will work :)

Comment: So no temp? :o  so while replaces my void bubblesort?  and what does aux stand for?  I'm totaly new to bubblesort and a beginner at c++ so I really need to understand this mate. Sorry for being a bit stupid ^^  and thanks for your answer, I will try the code you provided to the best of my abilities!

Comment: i used aux. it does the same thing you do with temp. sorry for not explaining correctly, i was in a rush

Comment: Not quite bubble-sort either, but at least it breaks the outer loop on a noswap, which is the important part. you're inner loop should be `i<n` or you invoke UB. And need to decrement the top-limit with each iteration. there is no sense in comparing to elements that have already found home. If no longer needed in the function, you an just decrement `n` after each outer iteration to do that.

Comment: i, n and one of the "mylist" is undefined. How and to what do I set them to? ><

Comment: you have to declare them.  int i,n,mylist[100];

Comment: n in your case equals 4.